# Evaluate $\int_2^\infty{\frac{3x-2}{x^2(x-1)}}$

Tags: integration

To be shown that $\int_2^\infty{\dfrac{3x-2}{x^2(x-1)}}=1-\ln2$

My thought: $\dfrac{3x-2}{x^2(x-1)}=\dfrac{3x}{x^2(x-1)}-\dfrac{2}{x^2(x-1)}$

• $\dfrac{3x}{x^2(x-1)}=\dfrac{3}{x(x-1)}=\ldots=-\dfrac{3}{x}+\dfrac{3}{x-1}$

• $\dfrac{2}{x^2(x-1)}=\ldots=-\dfrac{2}{x^2}+\dfrac{2}{x-1}$

But developing the sum of the integrals of the above two gives ln of infinite in my results. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can you please confirm the dots above? Although I have several times. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is some not right algebra, entry 2. Then there is a little trick needed once the algebra is fixed.

Comment: It is *not* true that $3/(x(x-1)) = -3/x + 3/(x-1)$.

Comment: But it is... :/

Comment: @darkchampionz: Yes, but can you say that of item 2? Calculate from your $\frac{-2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x-1}$ backwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

Write the integrand as: $$\frac{3x-2}{x^2(x-1)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}$$ in which $A,B$ and $C$ is unknown constants and so find the proper values for them. I think via this way you can find them easier than the way you noted. Indeed, $$\frac{Ax+B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}=\frac{(A+C)x^2+x(B-A)-B}{x^2(x-1)}$$ and therefore you get $$A+C=0, ~~B-A=3,~~-B=-2$$ and so...

Comment: Thanks a lot but what about my way? Because I can't find something wrong in it :|

Comment: Babak S.: $\color{red}{+1}$

Comment: Doesn't get any simpler...+1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks. If you don't mind, I use the form "..." as you have been doing. :-)

Comment: @darkchampionz: Dear friend, following Andre's comments will lead you right.

Comment: Nice work, Babak! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\dfrac{3x-2}{x^2(x-1)}=\frac A{x^2}+\frac Bx+\frac C{x-1}$$

$$\implies 3x-2=A(x-1)+Bx(x-1)+Cx^2=(B+C)x^2+x(A-B)-A$$

Comparing the constants in the above identity $A=2$

Comparing the  coefficients of $x,A-B=3\implies B=A-3=-1$

Comparing the  coefficients of $x^2,B+C=0\implies C=-B=1$

Alternatively, $$  3x-2=A(x-1)+Bx(x-1)+Cx^2$$

Putting $x=1$ in the above identity, $C=3\cdot 1-2=1$

Putting $x=0,-2=A(0-1)\implies A=2$

Comparing the  coefficients of $x^2,B+C=0\implies B=-C=-1$